# "Imagination is a force that manifests reality"

Tags: word-usage

Is this a metaphor? Just making sure.

I am certain it can be interpreted as one.

Comment: I'm confused. Which of the three nouns *(imagination, force, reality)* do you think is being used ***metaphorically***, and why? Come to that, what possible pair of "literal" and "figurative" meanings might be involved? In the absence of that information I think this question shows no evidence of "prior research".

Comment: It seems *imagination*, *force* and *manifest* all suggest metaphor in their etymology from *statue*, *physical strength*, and *hand strike*, but these metaphors are all so completely absorbed into our psyche that they are for all intents and purposes literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a metaphor. It can be intended to mean a few different things.

> Reality is perceived through the lens of your imagination.

This translates *manifest* to mean what is created in your mind.

> You can transform the world so long as you have the imagination to do it.

This translates *manifest* to mean what you create of your situation.

Comment: So you cannot interpret this as a metaphor, at all?

Comment: If you consider that _imagination_ is itself not the force that manifests reality but the driver or inspiration behind it, it could be interpreted as a metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to *force* could be viewed as metaphoric. However, one of the [definitions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/force) of *force* is:

> Mental or moral strength or power

Imagination is a mental activity that can exert influence.

It seems to me that this definition likely arose through the use of metaphor. But it has become common enough that it's now considered one of the actual meanings of the word, no longer a metaphor.